# Probability of being in a rectangle given probabilities of being on one side or the other of each line extending each edge of the rectangle

Tags: probability

Suppose that you have a rectangle in a 2D space.

I'm looking for the probability of being in this rectangle, knowing only the probability of being on one side or the other of each line extending each edge of the rectangle, shown by the colored probabilities in the following figure. [image]

Is it possible to get the probability of being in the rectangle given that piece of information, or is it not enough? The issue I suppose is that we don't know the probabilities of being into the corners (for instance $P(A\wedge B)$ for the top left corner) and I don't know if I can say that $P(\sim A\wedge\sim B\wedge\sim C\wedge\sim D)=(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))(1-P(D))$ since events might not be independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full description of the probabilities would consist of nine non-negative numbers (one for each region) summing to unity.  (This assumes the probability of being *on* any line is zero, for otherwise the description needs even more parameters.)  You suppose only four linear combinations of those nine numbers are known.  Together with the sum-to-unity restriction, that leaves up to $9-4-1=4$ dimensions of solutions.  Thus, unless the probabilities you specify are special (so that the solutions are limited to the boundary of this 4D space), **the answer must be no.**

With this in mind, let's consider two of the simplest possible situations.

1. Suppose the chance of each of the nine regions is $1/9.$ Then each boundary line divides the plane into pieces of probabilities $1/3$ and $2/3.$  With $p=1/9,$ we may draw this schematically as $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}p&p&p\\\hline p&p&p\\\hline p&p&p\end{array}$$ Outside each line the probability is $p+p+p=3p$ in all cases.

   In the next array the probabilities determined by the boundary lines are still the same:  $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}2p&0&p\\\hline 0&p&0\\\hline p&0&2p\end{array}$$ because each side has $3p$ probability, just as before.
2. Here, as another example, are infinitely many solutions where all probabilities are $1/2.$  The number $t$ is anywhere from $-1/4$ through $1/4.$ $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\frac{1}{4}+t&0&\frac{1}{4}-t\\\hline 0&0&0\\\hline \frac{1}{4}-t&0&\frac{1}{4}+t\end{array}$$

**Illustrating the possibility that in special cases the solution is unique,** suppose the probability outside each line is $1/4.$  The only way this can happen is  $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}0&\frac{1}{4}&0\\\hline\frac{1}{4}&0&\frac{1}{4}\\\hline0&\frac{1}{4}&0\end{array}$$ That's because the laws of probability imply the chance of the middle strip is $1-1/4-1/4=1/2$ and that can happen only if the probability of being in the interior square itself is $0,$ thereby placing $1/4$ into the left and right cells of the middle row, and this solution readily follows as the only one possible.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your neat explanation!

Answer (score -1):

In short, no. You have a 2D plane so there are two degrees of freedom for position in that plane. **You did not specify anything about the joint distribution of these two coordinates.** Thus you can't say anything definitive about the probabilities in the corners or the center. If you work in typical x/y coordinates and assume they are independent, then it becomes pretty straight forward to calculate the other probabilities.

Comment: Okay, and if I know that the two coordinates follow a multi-variate normal distrbution, with mutual independence (or covariance=0), I can easily compute the probability of being into the rectangle.

Comment: Agreed, if you know the joint distribution you can easily compute the probability of being in ANY rectangle using numerical integration. Or you may be able to do it analytically depending on the distribution.

In your example you've given some info about the distribution in terms of probabilities over a few regions of support. If you know the form of the distribution, the next step is to calculate the parameters of the distribution based on that information. Once the parameters are known (mean vector and covariance matrix in your case) you can integrate over any region you are interested in.